# Unable to automatically install auto-complete-c-headers on emacs

Tags: debugging, emacs, autocomplete, package

I am relatively new to emacs and I have been trying to setup a .emacs file which I could easily port from machine to machine without always having to manually reinstall all the packages each time. To accomplish this, I have used the solution from [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28932/how-to-automatically-install-all-packages-loaded-by-my-emacs-file-in-the-minimu) and it has worked successfully until now. Here is my code:

```
;; First, install use-package:
(package-initialize)

(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)

(dolist (package '(use-package))
  (unless (package-installed-p package)
           (package-install package)))

;; Then, install each of the following packages, if necessary:
(use-package paredit :ensure t)

(dolist (package '(auto-complete
                   auto-complete-c-headers
                   yasnippet
                   ))

  (unless (package-installed-p package)
    (package-install package))
     (require package))
```

In the above code, if I remove the reference to `auto-complete-c-headers`, everything works flawlessly. If I add it (like in the above snippet), emacs is unable to use my `.emacs` file. Running `emacs --debug-init` gives me the following:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Package `auto-complete-c-headers-' is unavailable")
  signal(error ("Package `auto-complete-c-headers-' is unavailable"))
  error("Package `%s-%s' is unavailable" auto-complete-c-headers "")
  package-compute-transaction(nil ((auto-complete-c-headers)))
  package-install(auto-complete-c-headers)
  (if (package-installed-p package) nil (package-install package))
  (while --dolist-tail-- (setq package (car --dolist-tail--)) (if (package-installed-p package) nil (package-install package)) (require package) (setq --dolist-tail-- (cdr --dolist-tail--)))
  (let ((--dolist-tail-- (quote (auto-complete auto-complete-c-headers yasnippet))) package) (while --dolist-tail-- (setq package (car --dolist-tail--)) (if (package-installed-p package) nil (package-install package)) (require package) (setq --dolist-tail-- (cdr --dolist-tail--))))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/morane/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 2236
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/morane/.emacs" "/home/morane/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #[0 "\205\262
```

I don't really understand what is happening. I have checked the repo with `M-x package-install` and it is there and available. Any thoughts? For your information, I am running emacs 24.5.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.3. Also, I have `use-package` installed.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi It works! What was the problem with the refreshing? Also, If you want to write a complete answer, I will accept it.